# Get “div:before {content” to fill full window width

Tags: html, css

I want the line containing “ New Subject“ to fill the full width of the window, with the text centred. This isn’t working. Why not? And how do I get it to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>

<style>
html body {width: 100%;}  /* enable following content to fill full screen width */

div.subject:before {content: "New Subject";
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: Yellow;
                    background-color: black;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align:center;
                    }
div.subject {border-top: thick solid;}
</style>

<title>html & CSS learning</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<p>Text before div</p>
<div class="subject">
<p>Text in the middle of div</p>
</div>
<p>Text after div</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[edited screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkVhS.jpg)

Comment: display:block to :before

Comment: This worked a treat